# What is the difference between these two sentences-with or without 'was'?

Tags: pronouns, auxiliary-verbs

> "I was willing to do whatever **was** necessary to be the wife he wanted."

> "I was willing to do whatever necessary to be the wife he wanted."

with or without "was" make a big difference?

Answer (score -1):

It does make a big difference, and in this case, it is necessary to increase "*was*"; you referred to a past action in your statement, which means the rest of the sentence referred to that action must be in the past tense. When you have doubts related to this stuff, try to read your sentence out loud, it shall sound weird, since you are referring to an action in the past that has no involvement with the present.

Comment: Davyd, instead of telling people "to read it out loud and it will sound funny" it's usually better to offer solid grammar rules to support your answer **and then** offer examples to illustrate.  Remember on ELL we aren't just providing answers to the person asking the question, but to *anyone* in the future searching for a similar answer.

Comment: I gave an example and tried to explain why it isn't right, I think people want a short and direct answer, if they wanted to see Oxford grammar's book they would look up this on internet.

Comment: I guess I described exactly why it is incorrect, you referred to a past action in your statement, which means the rest of the sentence referred to that action must be in the past tense. - since you are referring to an action in the past that has no involvement with the present.

Comment: Also, while the phrase "whatever necessary" is not common, is is a valid English idiom.  See [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=whatever+necessary%2Cwhatever's+necessary%2C+whatever+is+necessary%2Cwhatever+was+necessary&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) for relative usage and references, e.g. "I shall do whatever necessary for my king"

Comment: ELL **is** "looking it up on the Internet".  This site is highly ranked on Google and answers posted here frequently show up at the top of searches.  That's why we try and make our answers informed, accurate, and complete where possible.

Comment: Yeah, it is relative, but it doesn't describe where that sentence was used, and as the OP's question was placed in the past tense form, I presume "was necessary" would be the most proper for this statement.